# Set OnClick Listener on button inside list view in android

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a list view in my screen, every list item contains 2 text views and one button.
On button click i want to take the list item selected index to get some data from a vector.

This is my List Custom Adapter.But i don't know how to do that.

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServicesItems> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<ServicesItems> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView item = null;
        TextView description = null;
        Button subNowBtn;

        ServicesItems ii = getItem(position);

        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_of_servics_item_2, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        // cat_name = holder.gettitle();

        Resources resources = getResources();

        ServicesItems bean1 = (ServicesItems) servicesVector
                .elementAt(position);

        String cat_name_str = bean1.getService_name().toString();
        String descreption = bean1.getDescription().toString();


        item = holder.getItem();
        item.setText(bean1.getDescription());

        description = holder.getDescription();
        description.setText(bean1.getService_name());

         subNowBtn=holder.getSubButton();

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView description = null;
        private TextView item = null;
        private Button sub = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView getDescription() {
            if (null == description) {
                description = (TextView) mRow
                        .findViewById(R.id.category_tv);
            }
            return description;
        }

        public TextView getItem() {
            if (null == item) {
                item = (TextView)       
           mRow.findViewById(R.id.descreption_tv);
            }
            return item;
        }

        public Button getSubButton(){
            if(null==sub){
                sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe_now_btn);


            }
            return sub;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Adapter try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // What you want
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

**EDIT**

Your wrapper class:

```
public class YourWrapper
{
    private View base;
    private Button button;

    public YourWrapper(View base)
    {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Button getButton()
    {
        if (button == null)
        {
            button = (Button) base.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
        }
        return (button`);
    }
}
```

Change `sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe_now_btn);` into `sub=(Button) mRow.findViewById(R.id.subscribe_now_btn);`

Comment: i added this

      holder.getSubButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               // What you want
           }
       });
but it thorws a null pointer exc..

Answer (score 5):

You can get the index of list-view on button click, here are two examples:--

You can write these in your **`onClick`** method of listener.

**Example 1**

```
View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
```

**Example 2**

Set position using `setTag` when creating view

```
mybutton.setTag(position);
```

Get position in the listener

```
int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: thank you..all I needed was the getPositionForView method :) good answer