# Spinners in Listview are recreated before OnItemSelectedListener is executed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have a ListFragment (ListView should behave the same).  The List items have some Views in them including a Spinner.

What I would like to do is to update some of the data backing the ListFragment adapter when the Spinner value has changed.  For example, if the Spinner is in List item L[5], and the Spinner is selected at position 1, I want to update the backing data L[5].myVal = 1.  I'll then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter so that it can handle doing something with the new mVal value.

I've wrapped the Spinner in a SpinnerWithID class, which holds the index into the L array that the spinner is associated with.  I update the ID in the adapter getView() with the position passed in to getView().

The problem I am seeing is that by the time my SpinnerWithID onItemSelectedListener is executed, the SpinnerWithID that was selected may have been recycled by the ListFragment/ListView for another item in the list.

My listener function looks like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    SpinnerWithID spinner = (SpinnerWithID)parent;
    if (spinner != null) {          
        BackingData data = DataList.get(spinner.getListIndex());
        // do something with data
    }
}
```

So by the time this is called, the spinner's getListIndex() returns an unexpected value because the spinner itself may have been recycled for another item in the List.

How is this handled?

Edit:
My getView() looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    // First let's verify the convertView is not null
    if (convertView == null) {
        Context context = getContext();

        SpinnerWithID mySpinner = new SpinnerWithID(context);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(myFragment);

        // Add things here to the view
        myLayout.addView(mySpinner);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    // Update Views based on backing data

    // Keep Spinner synced
    holder.mySpinner.setListIndex(position);

    return v;
}
```

Edit:
Following the link that was posted by buzeeg, my code for the adapter now looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Build the view or use recycled view

    holder.mySpinner.setTag( Integer.valueOf(position) );
    holder.mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id)
        {
            myListFragment.updateBackingData(((Integer)parent.getTag()).intValue(), pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    });
}
```

However, I still have it sometimes updating the wrong backing data item.  My guess is that by the time onItemSelected is called, the view has been recycled and so the tag attached to the view has changed to the new row.  Darn.

Comment: You should update with the proper ID when recycling

Comment: I do update the spinner ID when recycling, but that is part of the problem--the spinner ID is updated before the onItemSelected() is processed, so when onItemSelected is finally called, it gets the new ID instead of the ID that generated the selection event.

Comment: can you post the getView method?

Comment: I've posted the essential parts of the getView().  I really don't see how you can use a Spinner in a ListView if the onItemSelected event does not allow the spinner to pass along a piece of data to identify the state of the spinner when the selection was made.

Comment: where are you creating the view ? some code is missing. Can you also add a bit of code of SpinnerWithID ?

Comment: Hello,  Yes, there is code missing from above.  The code is quite complex and most of it irrelevant to the question.  I'm creating the views manually within the convertview==null block.  It creates a toplevel LinearLayout and then adds views to the layout.   The SpinnerWithID is a class derived from Spinner with the addition of a private int holding the ID.  It has the get() and set() functions used in the code above, and nothing else.

Comment: After reading more posts similar to this one, it seems like it is not possible to have any kind of interactive widgets in a ListView if they use listeners to process actions.  Since none of the listeners I have looked at allow any kind of information passing to the handler and expect you to use the widget reference itself as an ID, I don't think that any of them can safely be used because of View recycling in ListView.  Are there any ideas on how to get around this, or is that just the way ListView is expected to be used (without any interactive sub-views)?

Comment: yes it can be done ! see this example with a button : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543087/set-onclick-listener-on-button-inside-list-view-in-android

Comment: Thank you for searching for an answer for me.  However, it still isn't working.  I have edited above how my adapter now looks.

Comment: I put a few Log.d() calls in the adapter getView() to track what views are getting assigned to different rows, and I do see it recycling views even when the list is not scrolling.